# How to share enums across C# and T-SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, enums

I have some enums in my C# code, for example:

```
public Enum
{
   Apple = 0,
   Orange = 1,
   Banana = 2,
}
```

And there are some SQL Server stored procedure which use these enums:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET val = 0 
WHERE id = 1; -- Orange = 1
```

It seems to me as duplication of code(enum definiton is duplicated in C# and as comment in T-SQL). I would like to share these enums across the project and languages (C# and T-SQL). What is a recommended approach for this?

Comment: a lookup table in sql which represents the Enum in C#

Comment: Please read [ask] and share your research. Plenty of existing questions discussing this very subject. The question is what _you_ want to support and what _you_ want to happen in certain scenarios. What if someone removes an enum member? What if someone alters one of the descriptions in the table? Which is the "master", the code or the database? From there on you can determine your approach.

Comment: Using enums for lookup tables might seem like a good idea at first glance, but it's usually not. what if you add Grapes? you will have to recompile the code to fit the data...